# Drop data in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

How do I get drop data in jquery? I'm a little surprise the data isn't available in the dragover event on chrome. How would I know if it's something droppable or not?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7KVph/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="item" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop here</div>
    <div ondragstart='drag(event)'>Drag me</div>
</div>
A:<span id="dragover_data">NA</span><br/>
B:<span id="drop_data">NA</span><br/>

C:<span id="dragover_data2">NA</span><br/>
D:<span id="drop_data2">NA</span>
<script>
function allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dragover_data').html('fail');
    $('#dragover_data').html(e.dataTransfer.getData("DataType"));
}

function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#drop_data').html('fail');
    $('#drop_data').html(e.dataTransfer.getData("DataType"));
}

function drag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("DataType", "MyData");
}
$('.item').on('dragover', function(e){
    $('#dragover_data2').html('fail');
    $('#dragover_data2').html(e.dataTransfer.getData("DataType"));
});
$('.item').on('drop', function(e){
    $('#drop_data2').html('fail');
    $('#drop_data2').html(e.dataTransfer.getData("DataType"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in `e.originalEvent`? typically if it's available on the original event, you'll always be able to find it on `e.originalEvent` if not otherwise. If it's not available on originalEvent, then it's not going to be available.

Comment: @KevinB: That did it. Thanks. I knew something like that exists. I looked for parent and target _event idk why I didnt think original. Maybe my eyes glazed over o and didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For properties not normalized by jQuery, you can find them on the originalEvent property.

```
function eventHandle (e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
}
```

it will contain all event properties that are on the event object generated by the browser.